# Use custom color schema in MUI theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to configure some colors in my theme, which are used by some categories in my application.

So I've setup a theme and use this in my component.

**theme.tsx**

```
import { createTheme, Theme } from '@mui/material/styles'
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors'

export const theme: Theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: blue[800]
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#19857b'
    },
    cat1: {
      main: red[700]
    }
  }
})
```

**circle.tsx**

```
import CircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FiberManualRecord'
import {theme} from '/shared/theme'

export function Circle() {
  return (
    <>
    <CircleIcon style={{ color: theme.palette.cat1.main }} />
    <CircleIcon style={{ color: theme.palette.cat1[200] }} />
    </>
  )
}
```

What I try to achieve is to set the color of some elements in a dynamic way. So the Circle in category 1 will get the color red. All colors which are needed are imported in the theme. I don't want to import all possible colors in the component itself.

But I also want to calculate the color of another element based on this. In the example above I would like to get 200 of red.

Comment: Do you want to use all shapes of a color by only passing say, `red` object to the theme?

Comment: @NearHuscarl I don't know the recommended way. At the end, I just need two or three grades of a color. But I want to calculate it instead of poluting the theme configuration by hardcoding all posiibilities...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, don't use `styles`, it's harder to override and MUI has better alternatives (`sx` prop/`styled` function) which provide the `theme` object for you when passing as a callback, so change your code to:

```
<CircleIcon sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.cat1.main }} />
```

Secondly, if you want to access other variants of the color like what you can with `primary` or `secondary`, use `augmentColor()` function to tell MUI generate the `dark`/`light`/`contrastText` colors automatically for you:

```
import {
  createTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
  Theme,
  lighten,
  darken
} from "@mui/material/styles";

const { palette } = createTheme();
const { augmentColor } = palette;
createTheme({
  palette: {
    // this will tell MUI to calculate the main, dark, light and contrastText
    // variants based on the red[500], and then merge the new properties with
    // the color object itself. The end result will be something like:
    // cat1: { '100': ..., '900': ..., light: ..., dark: ..., contrastText: ... }
    cat1: augmentColor({ color: red }),

    // this will tell MUI to calculate the main, dark, light and contrastText
    // variants based on the red[100], no other shades are passed unlike the above.
    cat2: augmentColor({ color: { main: red[100] } })

    // light and dark variants are generated in augmentColor using lighten() and
    // darken() function, if you want even more control, override the light and
    // dark properties yourself like this:
    cat3: augmentColor({
      color: {
        dark: darken(red[300], 0.6),
        main: red[300],
        light: lighten(red[300], 0.6)
      }
    })
  }
})
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks for that. How do I have to use `theme.palette.cat1.main` in case of the need of another gradient? Let's assume, there are two icons: the first should get main cat1 color (which is red) and the second should get at the end red[200].

Comment: @user3142695 the first approach in my answer will let you access all shades of the original color since you pass the whole object: `theme.palette.cat1.main` is the same as `theme.palette.cat1[500]`, you can also access other shade like: `theme.palette.cat1[200]`.

Comment: How is the calculation of `darken()` working? Is darken always +300 or something like that? I mean if main is red[500], is dark then red[300]?

Comment: @user3142695 I don't think so, the color object from MUI is handmade ([source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/colors/red.js)). Use `lighten` or `darken` to customize more to your need.

Comment: @user3142695 About the [implementation](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-system/src/colorManipulator.js#L233-L270), they just modify the r,g,b values of the color. For example, if you increase the second param value of `darken()`. It just subtracts more from those r,g,b values until it's completely dark (#000000).